# Check whether Marketing Cloud subscriber attribute is required or not

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, attribute

I am trying to create marketing Cloud subscriber using SOAP API. With in this process I need identify the subscriber attributes which are required. But when I retrieve susbcriber attributes as [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_profile_attributes_on_the_subscriber_object.htm) , I cannot identify whether the attribute is required or not.

Is there any other way to determine whether attributes are required or not through the SOAP API?

Comment: I don't think so. It's not deprecated, but the list model's been frowned upon for a long time and nobody in Product would have been given budget to tidy up holes in the API in this area for many years. What's the thinking behind using lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved through the "Describe" method. (See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/describe.htm)

I ran a describe call via the SOAP API for the object "Subscriber". It has a number of records return with a true/false value for the field "IsRequired", which should answer your question. Thanks, and happy Salesforce Marketing Clouding!

```
Name|DataType|IsRetrievable|IsUpdatable|IsRequired
ID|Int32|true|true|true
PartnerKey|String|true|true|false
CreatedDate|DateTime|true|true|false
Client.ID|Int32|true|true|true
Client.PartnerClientKey|String|true|true|false
EmailAddress|String|true|true|true
SubscriberKey|String|true|true|true
UnsubscribedDate|DateTime|true|true|false
Status|SubscriberStatus|true|true|true
EmailTypePreference|EmailType|true|true|true
Attributes|Attribute[]|false|true|NULL
PartnerType|String|false|true|NULL
Lists|SubscriberList[]|false|true|NULL
GlobalUnsubscribeCategory|GlobalUnsubscribeCategory|false|true|NULL
SubscriberTypeDefinition|SubscriberTypeDefinition|false|true|NULL
Addresses|SubscriberAddress[]|false|true|NULL
PrimarySMSAddress|SMSAddress|false|true|NULL
PrimarySMSPublicationStatus|SubscriberAddressStatus|false|true|NULL
PrimaryEmailAddress|EmailAddress|false|true|NULL
Locale|Locale|false|true|NULL
Client|ClientID|false|true|NULL
PartnerProperties|APIProperty[]|false|true|NULL
ModifiedDate|DateTime|false|true|NULL
ObjectID|String|false|true|NULL
CustomerKey|String|false|true|NULL
Owner|Owner|false|true|NULL
CorrelationID|String|false|true|NULL
ObjectState|String|false|true|NULL
IsPlatformObject|Boolean|false|true|NULL
```